# Proper params to convert mp3 to aac using avconv

Tags: python, mp3, aac, avconv

I am writing a little python script that converts `mp3` files to `aac`. I am doing so by using `avconv` and I am wondering if I am doing it right.
Currently my command looks like this:

```
avconv -i input.mp3 -ab 80k output.aac
```

This brings me to my first question: I am using `-ab 80k` as this works with my test-files. On some files I can go higher and use `100k`. But I'd prefer to have that always on the highest settings. Is there a way to say that?

The other question: I am using it in a python script. Currently I call it as a subprocess. What I'd prefer is not to do so, as this forces me to write a file to disc and then load it again when everything is done. Is there a way to only do it in memory? I am returning the file afterwards using `web.py` and don't need or want it on my disc? So would be cool not having to use temporary files at all.

Thanks for any tipps and tricks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the -ab option but if it is equivalent to -ar (specify the sample rate), I should point out that your ears won't be able to tell the difference between 80k and anything higher.
On the subject of temporary files, have you considered using /tmp or a specific `tmpfs` file system created for the purpose.

Edit:
In response to comment about tempfiles, yes you still use them but create them in /tmp or a tmpfs file system that you have created for the job. It should get cleared on reboot but I would expect you to delete the file once you have passed it on anyway.
The other point about lossless aac I may come back to you later.

Edit 2:
As I suspected the aac format is described as the logical successor to mp3 and I strongly suspect, you or someone else may know different, that as mp3 is what is termed as lossy, compressed i.e. bits ( no pun intended) missing, your desire to convert losslessly is doomed, in so much as the source is already lossy.
Of course, being no expert in the matter, I stand to be corrected.

Edit 3:
your comment about `too many frames` leads me to believe that you are conflating the two avconv options -ar and -b
The -b is used for video and specifies the output bit rate for video and audio. The way you are using it, I suspect that it is attempting to apply the same bit rate to audio and video but there is a limit on the audio stream.
You would have to use -b:v to tell avconv to set the video bit rate and leave the audio rate alone.
I suggest that you lose the -ab option and use -ar instead as that is audio only.

Comment: Thanks for your help: Concerning the `-ar`... When using it instead of the `-ab` param my machine complains with `[aac @ 0x11d0820] Unsupported sample rate 80000`. Any idea? Sorry... I am a media-file noobie :)

Comment: I'll also have a look at `tmpfs`, thx. But basically I will still use temp-files, right?

Comment: Ok... forget about the sample rate... :) I'd like to have a lossless aac file. So my input has a bitrate of 256k. I'd like to have the same for my aac file. But avconv complains about: `Too many bits per frame requested`. Would be great if you know how I could solve that issue...

Comment: @Georg too many bits per frame sounds like you are converting a video and not an mp3

Comment: Nope, it's an mp3, we'd just like to keep it on high quality. But I found out that if using `-acodec libvo_aacenc` it works. Thanks anyway!